# Handle changes in calculation logic for order system

Tags: pdf-generation, immutability, software-design, invoice, historical-db

I am currently dealing with a problem I can't find a answer to.

Imagin a software which holds information about Orders and OrderItems. Something like this:

```
OrderItem {
 ...
 price,
 amount
}

Order {
 ...
 total,
 vatTotal,
}

OrderDiscounts {
 ...
 percentage,
 targetGroup
}
```

**OrderItems can be subtotal as well holding no price and amount

All those information have to be taken into account for calculating the `vat` and the `total`.

As the order is finalized, the tables are getting locked via triggers to prevent changes on the finished order. The `total` and `vat total` of the `order` is saved on calculation time which happens while displaying the order information.

**First Problem:**
Time passes and there is a decision (or a bug) so that the logic for the calculation has to be updated. Let's be friendly and say it's a decision to adjust the logic how the system does the rounding.

Now the following problem occurs:
If you want to show an old `order` with it's `total` and `subtotals` it would have to recalculate everything with the new logic and obviously you run into a small difference.

How can you solve this problem in a elegant way?

**Second problem:**
You generate a PDF out of the `order` on the time of finalizing. Again time passes and the software gets updated/adjusted. For example a table header for the order is changed. If you would reprint the order again it wouldn't be the same anymore.

**Possible solution first problem**
One solution which comes to my mind is to save all information visible to the user in database fields. This would require to add fields like `lineTotal` for almost everything.

Are there other possible solutions which I'm not able to see?

**Second problem**
Is there any other way than just saving the PDF somewhere and reference the once generated pdf? Is this even an issue?